# Deploying to IONOS failed

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, ionos

I want to deploy my project on Github to IONOS using Github workflow.

Here is my `deploy-now.yaml`;

```
name: Deploy Now

on:
  - push
  - workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  deploy-now:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Fetch project data
        uses: ionos-deploy-now/retrieve-project-info-action@v1
        id: project
        with:
          api-key: ${{ secrets.IONOS_API_KEY }}
          project: ${{ secrets.IONOS_PROJECT_ID }}
          service-host: api-eu.ionos.space
      - name: checkout
        if: ${{ steps.project.outputs.deployment-enabled == 'true' }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: 'recursive'
      - name: Setup Node.js 14.x
        if: ${{ steps.project.outputs.deployment-enabled == 'true' }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
      - name: Prepare project environment
        if: ${{ steps.project.outputs.deployment-enabled == 'true' }}
        run: |
          npm install --global yarn
          yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - name: Build project
        if: ${{ steps.project.outputs.deployment-enabled == 'true' }}
        run: yarn build
        env:
          mint.hopegalaxy: ${{ steps.project.outputs.site-url }}
          app: true
      - name: Deploy build
        if: ${{ steps.project.outputs.deployment-enabled == 'true' }}
        uses: ionos-deploy-now/deploy-to-ionos-action@v1
        with:
          api-key: ${{ secrets.IONOS_API_KEY }}
          bootstrap-deploy: ${{ steps.project.outputs.bootstrap-deploy }}
          branch-id: ${{ steps.project.outputs.branch-id }}
          dist-folder: build
          project: ${{ secrets.IONOS_PROJECT_ID }}
          remote-host: ${{ steps.project.outputs.remote-host }}
          service-host: api-eu.ionos.space
          storage-quota: ${{ steps.project.outputs.storage-quota }}
```

But when I push what I have done to Github, I met this error `Publish directory 'build' does not exist in project`

I attached image;
[image]

As you can see from the image, building has been successfully done.

I am not sure why this issue happens.

Any comment would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure the unhandled promise rejection has nothing to do with this?

Comment: I think so rethab. As you can see from the image, the building has been successfully done.

Comment: Can you add a new step `run: ls build` to make sure the directory is created?